# Timeseries pandas changing name columns IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

[IMAGE OF THE DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn4GG.png) I had dates in one column, set them as a time series, and then transposed them so that each year has its own column. Some columns have the correct year, but the wrong date. I would like to set them all to the same month and day, but when I try to modify them, I get an error "IndexError: too many indices for array".

I tried these 2 methods:

```
df_top100.rename(columns={'2012-12-31 00:00:00': '2012-01-01 00:00:00'}, inplace=True)
#df_top100.rename(columns={'2013-12-31': '2013-01-01'}, inplace=True)
#df_top100.rename(columns={'2016-12-31': '2016-01-01'}, inplace=True)
```

Dataset, first line:

```
year    2005-01-01  2006-01-01  2007-01-01  2008-01-01  2009-01-01  2010-01-01  2011-01-01  2012-12-31  2013-12-31  2014-01-01  2015-01-01  2016-12-31
country                                             
Australia   2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 9.0 6.0 8.0 11.0    11.0    6.0
```

Last column:

```
print print(df_top100.columns[-1])
2016-12-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) in columns - extract years and convert to datetimes:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(['2012-12-31 00:00:00','2013-12-31','2016-12-31'])
df_top100 = pd.DataFrame(columns=d)

df_top100.columns = pd.to_datetime(df_top100.columns.year, format='%Y')
print (df_top100)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2012-01-01 00:00:00, 2013-01-01 00:00:00, 2016-01-01 00:00:00]
Index: []
```

For strings use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df_top100.columns = df_top100.columns.strftime('%Y-01-01')
print (df_top100)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2012-01-01, 2013-01-01, 2016-01-01]
Index: []
```

Comment: i updated the question with an image

Comment: @spike424 - Solution not working?

Comment: df_top100.columns = df_top100.columns.strftime('%Y-01-01')
yes this one worked thx

Answer (score 1):

If you provide an small example that we can copy, it is much easier to help.

looking at your code, I guess it does not work since you are trying to reference a datetime object with a string. Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

df_top100.rename(columns={datetime(2012, 12, 31): '2012-01-01 00:00:00'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: year 2005-01-01 2006-01-01 2007-01-01 2008-01-01 2009-01-01 2010-01-01 2011-01-01 2012-12-31 2013-12-31 2014-01-01 2015-01-01 2016-12-31
country            
Australia 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 9.0 6.0 8.0 11.0 11.0 6.0


this is the first line of the dataset.
year       2011 2012
country
austria    3.2    3.3
if I print print(df_top100.columns[-1])
i have 2016-12-31 00:00:00